# Is it posible to see the async storage current limit React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I would like to know how much is the remaining memory of a react native application using async storage.

I know in general is about 6 MB the total consumption, but I did not see in any of the methods of async storage "expo" from react native how much is the current consumption and how much is it allowed to be used from the current device.

I would love to have something like:

```
const currentMemory = AsyncStorage.currentMemoryConsumption();
const deviceMemoryLimit = AsyncStorage.deviceMemoryLimit();
```

And then I would be able to know the current memory consumption make an analysis and provide meaningful information to my client.

I don't see any information either in the current implementation of react native async storage from community.

Is it possible to know about the current memory state before using async storage to save an item?

Thanks in advance for the reading and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no way to get AsyncStorage remaining size at the moment.

Probably the best course of action would be to just increase the limit by following official documentation and trigger a cleaning task if you reach a limit.
https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/master/docs/OLD/advanced/IncreaseDbSize.md

This discussion explores the related topics but consensus is to just increase storage limit and be careful.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3387